# Apex Query on ContentVersion object and get all record

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, contentversion, contentdocument

Apex Query on ContentVersion object and get all records, but the record are coming on current login user owned, not all records are coming. for example i am login with administrator account and want to see all records on my page, but they just return the records owned by me . is it any work around to get all records.

Answer (score 2):

The ContentVersion Sobject [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) mentions

> Users (including users with the “View All Data” permission) can only
>   query files they have access to, including:
>
> - All Salesforce CRM Content files in libraries they're a member of and    in their personal library, regardless of library permissions
>     (API    version 17.0 and later).
> - All Chatter files they own, posted on their profile, posted on groups they can see, and shared directly with them (API version
>     21.0 and later).

Comment: Yes i have read this documentation thats why i ask if there any workaround to get all records ?